Uncommon Date Format Issue in R
enter image description hereHow to format this date (as shown in picture) in R ?
I tried format function - activity_df$ActivityDate <- format(activity_df$ActivityDate, format="%m/%d/%y") but it didn't work. It reflected the same wrong date as it was before.
